# Automaticly file screenshots in folder on desktop

Tags: automator, screen-capture

I take lots of screenshots that fill up my desktop very quickly, what im trying to do is set a system where all screenshots will automatically get saved to a screenshots folder on my desktop.

Ive tried to set an automator action to do this, but couldn't figure out exactly how to do this, any ideas / guidance much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the default screenshot location via the Terminal running the following commands:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/yourpathhere
killall SystemUIServer
```

In your case to save the screenshots in a folder on the desktop the path would be /Users/userName/Desktop/*yourfoldername*